# How to get all mocked function calls in vitest?

Tags: vitest

I am able to assert that a method has been called with particular arguments, e.g.

```js
expect(
  services.paidProjectAnalytics.logFirstPaymentReceivedEvent,
).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  paidProjectId,
});
```

However, how do I get all invocations of `services.paidProjectAnalytics.logFirstPaymentReceivedEvent` and their arguments?

As an example, in Sinon this would be simply [`spy.args` property](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `chai` (which `vitest` is using under the hood) as follows (having installed `sinon` and `sinonChai`):

```
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import chai from 'chai'
chai.use(sinonChai)

const add = (x, y) => {
  return x + y
}

test('call args', function() {
  add(3,7)
  expect(add).to.have.been.calledWith(3,7)
})
```